# Can Splithalf Reliability Be Caclulated for an Aggregate Measure?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reliability, psychology, d-prime

I have been asked by a journal editor to provide the splithalf reliability for an aggregate dependent variable, *d'*, which is a Signal Detection parameter that captures perceptual sensitivity. However, *d'* cannot be calculated on a trial-by-trial level, because *d'* is inherently an aggregate measure (see calculation information below). My question is as follows: Is it possible to calculate the splithalf reliability for an aggregate measure such as *d'*, given that there is no trial-level data that can be used for usual splithalf reliability calculations? It sounds as if the editor is asking for a bivariate correlation between *d'* from the fist and second halves of the task, but that does not correspond to my understanding of what splithalf reliability is meant to meausure.

*Calculation information: *d'* is calculated by 1) calculating the **rate** of hits (when a signal [i.e., target] stimulus is correctly identified), 2) calculating the **rate** of false alarms (when a non-signal [i.e., non-target] stimulus is incorrectly identified as a signal stimulus), 3) z-transforming both values (generating the inverse of the Cumulative Normal Distribution Function for hits and false alarms, separately), and 4) calculating z-transformed(Hits) - z-transformed(False alarms).*

Comment: This seems like a weird request. Split half reliability depends on where you split. Coefficient (Cronbach's) alpha is the average of all possible split half reliability estimates. 
I don't think you can do it with this data.